# Swift TableView Footer ActivityIndicatorView like Facebook. when scrolling down for more data loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i want to make a TableView footer activityIndicatorView like Facebook, when scrolling down for more data loading from web, also can say infiniteScrollingView.

my infiniteScrolling is ok, but have three problem there

1. footerView's background space is not going to hide after complete data loading from web.
2. activityIndicatorView is moving up and down, but i want to put activityIndicatorView always down like Facebook.
3. want to show activityIndicatorView if data have

**NetworkRequestAPI Request**

```
import Foundation

class NetworkRequestAPI {


    static func getPropductListByCategory(productId : Int, pageNo : Int , completion: @escaping ([Product]? , Error?) -> ()){

        let url = URL(string: Configuration.BASE_URL+"/product-by/type?product_type_id="+String(productId)+"&page="+String(pageNo))

        var categoryObject = [Product]()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (urlContent, response, error) in
            if error != nil {

            }
            else {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent!) as! [String:Any]

                    let products = json["products"] as? [String: Any]
                    //   productCount = (json["product_count"] as? Int)!

                    let items = products?["data"] as? [[String:Any]]
                    items?.forEach { item in
                        let oProduct = Product()

                        oProduct.product_id = item["product_id"] as? Int
                        oProduct.product_name = item["product_name"] as? String
                        oProduct.product_image = item["product_image"] as? String

                        let ratingItem = item["rating_info"] as? [String: AnyObject]

                        let rating = RatingInfo()
                        rating.final_rating = ratingItem?["final_rating"] as? String

                        oProduct.rating_info = rating

                        categoryObject.append(oProduct)
                    }
                    completion(categoryObject, nil)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }  
}
```

**ListTableView Class**

```
class ListTableView: UITableViewController {

    var isInitUILoad = true
    var arrProduct = [[Product]]()
    var pageNo = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initUILoad() 
    }

    func initUILoad(){
        ActivityIndicator.customActivityIndicatory(self.view, startAnimate: true)

        NetworkRequestAPI.getPropductListByCategory(productId: product_id, pageNo: pageNo) { (products, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if products != nil {
                    self.pageNo += 1

                    self.arrProduct.append(products!)
                    print(self.arrProduct.count)
                }else{
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }

                ActivityIndicator.customActivityIndicatory(self.view, startAnimate: false)

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
                self.isInitUILoad = false
            })
        }
    }

    func loadMore(complition:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        NetworkRequestAPI.getPropductListByCategory(productId: product_id, pageNo: pageNo) { (products, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if error != nil{
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }
                if products != nil && products?.count ?? 0 > 0{

                    self.pageNo += 1

                    self.arrProduct.append(products!)
                    self.tableView?.insertSections([self.arrProduct.count - 1], with: .fade)
                }else{
                    print("no product left")
                }
                complition(true)
            })
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: categoryCellid, for: indexPath) as! ListTableCell
        var categoryObject = arrProduct[indexPath.section]
        cell.product = categoryObject[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 115.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: footerCellid) as! HeadFooterCell

        if !isInitUILoad {
            footerView.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            loadMore(complition: { (isDone) in
                footerView.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            })
        }
        return footerView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50   
    }

}
```

** HeadFooterCell**

```
class HeadFooterCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    var activityIndicatorView : UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        var activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        activityIndicatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        return activityIndicatorView
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(activityIndicatorView)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: activityIndicatorView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(50)]|", views: activityIndicatorView)    
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if anyone have a very good idea "pull to refresh" instead of activityIndicatorView. that also can